# Angular player not recognized in content partial

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to build a SPA with AngularJS and WP API. I'm using partials to load in `ng-view` all the content I need to show through routing. Upon this I added `Plangular` which is an AngularJS Player that uses Soundcloud API.

This is my main js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['plangular','ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'slick']);


//Config the route
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', 'plangularConfigProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider, plangularConfigProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    plangularConfigProvider.clientId = 'CLIEND_ID';
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: myLocalized.partials + 'main.html',
            controller: 'Main'
        })

        .when('/blog/:slug', {
            templateUrl: myLocalized.partials + 'content.html',
            controller: 'Content'
        })



    $httpProvider.interceptors.push([function() {
        return {
            'request': function(config) {
                config.headers = config.headers || {};
                //add nonce to avoid CSRF issues
                config.headers['X-WP-Nonce'] = myLocalized.nonce;

                return config;
            }
        };
    }]);
}]);

//Main controller
app.controller('Main', ['$scope', 'WPService', function($scope, WPService) {
    WPService.getPosts(1);
    $scope.data = WPService;
}]);

//Content controller
app.controller('Content', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $http.get('wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=' + $routeParams.slug).success(function(res) {
        $scope.post = res[0];
        document.querySelector('title').innerHTML =  res[0].title.rendered + ' | Going Solo ';
        console.log(res);
    }).error(function(res, status) {
        if (status === 404) {
            $scope.is404 = true;
            document.querySelector('title').innerHTML = 'Page not found | Going Solo';
            $scope.errorMessage = 'Error: ' + res[0].message;
        }
    });

    $http.get('wp-json/wp/v2/media?filter[post_parent]=' + $routeParams.slug + '&filter[posts_per_page]=-1').success(function(res) {
        if (res.length > 1) {
            $scope.media = res;
        }
    });
}]);
```

All the posts in the `main` are loaded through a Service:

```
function WPService($http) {

    var WPService = {
        categories: [],
        posts: [],
        pageTitle: 'Latest Posts:',
        currentPage: 1,
        totalPages: 1,
        currentUser: {}
    };



    WPService.getPosts = function(page) {
        return $http.get('wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?page=' + page + '&filter[posts_per_page]=1').success(function(res, status, headers){
            page = parseInt(page);
            console.log(res);
            if ( isNaN(page) || page > headers('X-WP-TotalPages') ) {
                _updateTitle('Page Not Found', 'Page Not Found');
            } else {
                if (page>1) {
                    _updateTitle('Posts on Page ' + page, 'Posts on Page ' + page + ':');
                } else {
                    _updateTitle('Home', 'Latest Posts:');
                }

                _setArchivePage(res,page,headers);
            }
        });
    };


app.factory('WPService', ['$http', WPService]);
```

And the player is loaded correctly (basically I declare Plangular directive):

```
<div plangular="{{post.acf.soundcloud_song}}" 
  class="flex flex-center">
  <button ng-click="playPause()"
    title="Play/Pause"
    type="button" class="flex-none h4 mr2 button button-transparent button-grow rounded">
    <svg ng-if="player.playing !== track.src" class="icon geomicon" data-icon="play" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32" style="fill:currentcolor"><path d="M4 4 L28 16 L4 28 z "></path></svg>
    <svg ng-if="player.playing === track.src" class="icon geomicon" data-icon="pause" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32" style="fill:currentcolor"><path d="M4 4 H12 V28 H4 z M20 4 H28 V28 H20 z "></path></svg>
  </button>
</div>
```

where the scope variable is the soundcloud url of the song taken by the `http get`. But when I click on a post and I load the content with the controller, the track obviously keep streaming but the button of the plangular player inside the content.html doesn't work, or better, it just stop the song.

Here is a link to better understand the behavior: http://new.wearegoingsolo.com/
If you click on a post the plangular player inside it, it doesn't work. And if track is playing it just stop it.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please reduce your code to only the relevant part you're having issue with (Create a [mcve])

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I removed the useless code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `plangular` directive, you set the `src` by the *plangular* attribute of the element in the `link` function:

```
var src = attr.plangular;
```

On the main page you create the player inside `ngRepeat` so when you call the `plangular` directive, you already have the url of the song, because it associated with the element in the current loop:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in data.posts">
    <div plangular="{{post.acf.soundcloud_song}}"></div>
</div>
```

On the post page (In the `content.html` view) you also bind the directive the same way, but the directive is getting initiated **before** the post details were returned from the server!

In order to fix this, you must make sure that you call this directive only when you actually have the source url of the song.

Change (In the `content.html` view):

```
<div plangular="{{post.acf.soundcloud_song}}" class="flex flex-center">
```

To:

```
<div plangular="{{post.acf.soundcloud_song}}" ng-if="post.acf" class="flex flex-center">
```

By adding `ng-if="post.acf"` you ensure that the element will be created when you have the real data in the controller.